# Python use output from function in another function

Tags: python, function, selenium

Here is my code:
in function `add_new_employee` I'm getting `employee_id` and then i want to use that `employee_id` in my next function `new_employee_added`
Can someone help me with that? thank you

```
employee_id= ()
def add_new_employee(driver, first_name, last_name):
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#menu_pim_viewPimModule").click()
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[name='btnAdd']").click()
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#firstName").send_keys(first_name)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#lastName").send_keys(last_name)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#photofile").\
        send_keys(os.path.abspath("cloud-computing-IT.jpg"))
    global employee_id
    employee_id = 
   driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#employeeId").get_attribute("value")
    return employee_id

def new_employee_added(driver):
    global employee_id
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#menu_pim_viewPimModule").click()
    for i in range(1, 50):
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_link_text("%s" % employee_id).click()
            break
        except NoSuchElementException:
            driver.find_element_by_link_text("%s" % i).click()

def test_new_employee(driver, first_name="Patrick", last_name="Patterson"):
    login(driver, username="Admin", password="Password")
    # add new user with First Name, Last Name and Photo
    add_new_employee(driver,first_name, last_name)
    #verify that new employee added
    new_employee_added(driver)
    #ckeck if we got the right employee page
    logout(driver)
```

in function `add_new_employee` I'm getting `employee_id` and then i want to use that `employee_id` in my next function `new_employee_added`
Can someone help me with that? thank you

Comment: def new_employee_added(driver, employee_id): ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just save output of add_new_employee in local variable and then pass it as argument to your new_employee_added function.

Comment: how can i use local variable in another function? i've tried global and it works

Comment: @Ihor Harmatii, yes, you are right, but I meant using it in your test_new_employee function and save as local variable in this function. Global variable is fine also, but try to avoid using them because it could bring a mess. You can just add extra parameter to your new_employee_added function like new_employee_added(driver, employee_id).

Answer (score 1):

Add the parameter to the function definition, then pass it in when you call it:

```
def new_employee_added(driver, employee_id):
    ...

def test_new_employee(driver, first_name="Patrick", last_name="Patterson"):
    login(driver, username="Admin", password="Password")
    # add new user with First Name, Last Name and Photo
    employee_id = add_new_employee(driver,first_name, last_name)
    #verify that new employee added
    new_employee_added(driver, employee_id)
    #ckeck if we got the right employee page
    logout(driver)
```

Comment: when i do it this way function `add_new_employee` runs two times, i just need output from it

Comment: @IhorHarmatii no it doesn't. See my edit, hopefully that's clearer.

Comment: it runed 2 times, i wondering why, so i've tried use global var for that, look at my code, i edit it

Comment: @IhorHarmatii if it runs twice then there's some other code you're not showing.

Comment: could you edit my code, because i don't understand a little bit, thank you